# How to get Value from html string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html string like this which response from API:

```
const response = `
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <code>Value I want to get<br></code>
  </body>
</html>
`;
```

So the content maybe dynamic but the tag `<code>` is unique. I want to have some more solutions on this to see what is the best solution.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("code")` is what you should be looking for

Comment: "*I want to have some more solutions…*" You haven't shown any solutions, so this is just a request for free code.

Comment: Nope. This string come from API and we cannot get the value inside `<code>` by document.

Comment: @HoangTranSon yeah didn't see the string thing. Someone has already provided a correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert your HTML string into a Document object which you can then use `querySelector()` to get your desired value:

```js
const response = `
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <code>Value I want to get<br></code>
  </body>
</html>
`;

const {body} = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
const value = body.querySelector('code').innerText; // find <code> tag and get text
console.log(value);
```